# Youtube Direct - Migration from AuthSub to OAuth

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have problem with YouTube Direct project...

Made all as it is here: [YouTube Direct: Getting Started Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1pxGe3zLXg)

When I click on "Authenticate" here:

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/55b0r4vax/)

I have a problem with authentication:

> Deprecated APIs were discontinued on April 20th, 2015. To restore service, update to the replacement API."

I was on stackoverflow, yt g+ etc... but cant find solution.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

That video is from Dec 18, 2009 and refers to a version of the YouTube API that is out of date and no longer works.

You will need to find a tutorial for the current version of the youtube API V3.